# Django manage.py sqclear all apps

Tags: python, django, fabric, manage.py

I want to get all apps sql clear code in Django. I can use `./manage.py sqlclear`  but I need to specify an appname, so is just for one app.

Is there a way or command to execute `sqlclear` over all installed apps ?

Answer (score 1):

[Django extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_extensions.html) has `reset_db` command which is handy.

Sample run:

```
(junction)➜  junction git:(master) ✗ ./manage.py reset_db
Monkey patching...

You have requested a database reset.
This will IRREVERSIBLY DESTROY
ALL data in the database "/Users/kracekumar/code/junction/db.sqlite3".
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Reset successful.
```

Comment: it throws psycopg2.ProgrammingError: permission denied to create database

Comment: @levi: Probably that user/role doesn't have access to create database. `GRANT ALL ON db TO ROLE;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sqlflush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#sqlflush) for printing out database flushing command or directly use [flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#flush) for removing all data from database.